# How to show id after title in php url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to modify in my php url. Currently my url is like http://localhost/classified/1-Health-and-Beauty and it is working well. Now, i want to show my url like http://localhost/classified/Health-and-Beauty-1.

here is my php:

```
    <?php 
      $categories_name = $_GET['categories_name'];
      $result = "SELECT * FROM sub_categories where 
        categories_name='$categories_name'";
        $data =mysqli_query ($conn, $result);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
        { 

          $sub_categories_name = $row['sub_categories_name'];
          $sub_id = $row['sub_id'];

            $sub_categories_name  = urldecode($sub_categories_name );  
            $sub_categories_name = str_replace(' ', '-', $sub_categories_name); 

            $url = '/classified/' . urlencode($sub_id) . '-' . urlencode($sub_categories_name);

        ?>

<a href="<?php echo $url ?>">
    <div class="cat-box p-0 m-0 cat-url">
        <p class="subcat-url"><?php echo $sub_categories_name;?></p>
    </div>
</a>
<?php }?>
```

here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\d+) category-classifieds.php?sub_id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: no, can you help me out with that @ jeto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### .htaccess

You want to match URLs *ending* with a number instead of URLs starting with a number. See "Start of String and End of String Anchors" on [this page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

Replace:

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+) category-classifieds.php?sub_id=$1 [L]
```

with:

```
RewriteRule (\d+)$ category-classifieds.php?sub_id=$1 [L]
```

### PHP Script

You need to accordingly change the way URLs are generated.

Replace:

```
$url = '/classified/' . urlencode($sub_id) . '-' . urlencode($sub_categories_name);
```

with:

```
$url = '/classified/' . urlencode($sub_categories_name) . '-' . urlencode($sub_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The php is not ok. The url is still generated with id before name. Modify this:

```
$url = '/classified/' . urlencode($sub_id) . '-' . urlencode($sub_categories_name);
```

To:

```
$url = '/classified/' . urlencode($sub_categories_name) . '-' . urlencode($sub_id);
```

Comment: i have already tried but it doesnt display any data because the link is fully dependent on sub_id

Comment: It isn't ok to just put a rule based on last numbers in url because you can have multiple routes ending in numbers. You have to create a more complex rule that also includes `classified`.

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa I guess the .htaccess is only within the `classified/` (physical) directory. Only thing that would make sense looking at the current rewrite rule. In that case, we can suppose it's only for classifieds.